# Relationship between the SVD and correlation matrices

Tags: correlation, linear-algebra, svd

I'm reading *[Data Driven Science and Engineering](http://databookuw.com/)* by Kutz and Brunton to understand more about the SVD.

Consider $X = U\Sigma V$, $XX^*$, and $X^*X$ where $X \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n} $

In particular, consider that:

$XX^*U = U\Sigma^2$

and

$X^*XV = V\Sigma^2$

In the book, the authors mention that since the singular values are arranged in descending order by magnitude (in $\Sigma$), the columns of $U$ are ordered by how much correlation they capture in the **columns** of $X$, and the columns of $V$ are ordered by how much correlation they capture in the **rows** of $X$. I can't seem to understand why this is the case. In particular, I think it's the opposite: i.e that the columns of $U$ are ordered by how much correlation they capture in the **rows** of $X$, while the columns of $V$ are ordered by how much correlation they capture in the **columns** of $X$.

I think this is the case because when you compute $XX^*$, $XX^*_{i,j}$ corresponds to the dot product of the ith row of $X$ with the jth column of $X^*$ (i.e the jth row of $X$), and thus you are taking the dot product of two rows of $X$ (thus computing their correlation). This leads me to believe that $U$ has to do with correlation in the rows of $X$, not the columns. Similarly, when you compute $X^*X$, $X^*X_{i,j}$ takes the dot product of the ith row of $X^*$ (i.e the ith column of $X$) with the jth column of $X$, and thus you are taking the dot product of two columns of $X$ (thus computing their correlation). This again leads me to believe that $V$ has to do with correlation in the columns of $X$, not the rows.

I'd appreciate if someone could clarify.

Moreover, I'm trying to understand precisely how the fact that the columns of $U$ are hierarchically ordered (or $V$, but let's just consider $U$ for now) relates to the fact that each column is better able to capture correlation in $XX^*$ (i.e column 1 can better capture correlation than column 2, column 2 better than column 3 etc...). Here's how I currently understand it:

$$XX^* = U\Sigma^2 U^*$$ $$= 
\begin{bmatrix}
    \vert & & \vert \\
    u_1   & ... & u_m   \\
    \vert & & \vert
\end{bmatrix}
\Sigma^2
\begin{bmatrix}
    \text{---} & u_1^T & \text{---} \\
    & \text{...} \\
    \text{---} & u_m^T & \text{---}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

We can write this as a dyadic summation (I believe this is what the following summation is called, I could be wrong though):
$\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sigma_i\vec{u_i}\vec{u_i}^T$

Now, it is my hunch that for example $\sigma_1\vec{u_1}\vec{u_1}^T$ has a larger Frobenius norm than $\sigma_2\vec{u_2}\vec{u_2}^T$ because that would make it "closer" to $XX^*$, and thus better able to represent it (and hence better able to represent correlations). Actually as I'm writing this, I believe I found the answer to my second question, and convinced myself that this is indeed must be the case. Since the $\vec{u}$ vectors are orthonormal, and the singular values are hierarchically organized, it must be that $\sigma_1\vec{u_1}\vec{u_1}^T$ in the Frobenius sense is larger than $\sigma_2\vec{u_2}\vec{u_2}^T$. Since this has pretty much answered my second question, perhaps someone can add in additional insights!

Comment: Simple counting casts doubt on your assertions: typically, there are far more rows $n$ of $U$ than columns $p$.  How, then, can a small number $p$ of columns "capture," in any sense, an $n\times n$ correlation matrix?

Comment: @whuber can you please be more specific about which part of my question you're responding to? Also, isn't $U$ typically square? (unless you're truncating it)

Comment: I am responding only to the first question in your post.  Because posts need to focus on one question, I didn't read further.  When $X$ is an $n\times p$ matrix, $U$ typically is $n\times p.$  Sometimes it has fewer columns, because columns corresponding to zero singular values have no effect.

Comment: @whuber hmm according to my understanding that $U$ ($n \times p$) would correspond to the $U$ in economy SVD, not the full SVD. In any case, I believe the second part of the post responds to your (rhetorical?) question.

Comment: @whuber and please let me know if it doesn't! I may have misunderstood you.

Comment: @whuber Couldn't you say the same, that $V$ couldn't capture the correlations among the (larger number of rows of) $X$? Indeed the rank of either "correlation" matrix $XX^T$ or $X^TX$ is only p and is being represented as a sum of p rank 1 matrices.

Comment: @AnIgnorantWanderer In OP, first eqn should be $X=U\Sigma V^*$ i believe. And I agree with you that to the extent $XX^T$ is correlation matrix, it captures the correlations between rows of $X$ not columns.

Comment: How is $XX^T$ a correlation or covariance matrix? Don't we first have to subtract the row means?

Comment: @Don That's correct.  It appears that many accounts of correlation from the machine learning literature exist in a context where the columns of $X$ have first been centered (and maybe even scaled).

Comment: @whuber Ah, that would explain why they call it a correlation vs a covariance matrix as well. And the divide by sample size could be thown in to the scaling for good measure..

Comment: @AnIgnorantWanderer In this lecture https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WmDnaoY2Ivs&list=PLMrJAkhIeNNSVjnsviglFoY2nXildDCcv&index=4 Steve Bruntun seems to agree be arguing what you are saying, which we agree with, and is the opposite of what the book says..